# Installation of MATLAB on 22.04 finished but cannot start it

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, matlab

I am on a Lenovo Legion 5 Pro with dual boot, Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I am trying to install MATLAB R2022b on the Ubuntu.

I downloaded the current zip file from Mathworks and pretty much followed the instructions from https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-matlab-on-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish-linux. This means that I unzipped the installation files into `~/Documents/matlab` and then installed it into `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2022b/`.

The installation GUI opened, everything seemed to work fine, after it got to 100% it closed by itself. Then, I tried to start MATLAB using Activities, and there is no MATLAB. I tried typing `matlab` into the terminal, it doesn't know the command.

Further inspection shows that there is no `matlab.desktop` file to be found, and `whereis matlab` comes up empty.

There are files in the directory /usr/local/MATLAB/R2022b/ though:
[image]

And this is what is in the `bin`:
[image]

Double clicking on `matlab` opens up the file as a text file and here it also doesn't know the command:

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2022b/bin$ matlab
matlab: command not found
```

At this point I have no idea if MATLAB is actually installed and there just isn't any link to the executable from a directory on my path OR something went wrong in the installation. Does anyone have any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: what's in the bin directory?

Comment: I added it to the question itself

Comment: run ./matlab from the bin directory  rather than matlab

Comment: omg why didn't I think of that... Thanks! Do you know by any chance how I can create a link so that it shows up in my Activities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cd to the matlab bin directory and run matlab

```
cd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2022b/bin
./matlab
```

I imagine the whole path would work

I think [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/1282203/how-do-i-add-a-shortcut-to-the-show-applications-menu-in-ubuntu-17) shows you how to add it to activites. The accepted answer written by [shade of blue](https://superuser.com/users/862465/shade-of-blue) says

> The obscure directory you're looking for would be: /usr/share/applications.
>
> Just have a look at the *.desktop files there, choose one that doesn't have too much cruft, copy it to a new .desktop file and edit to reflect your app.

If that doesn't work, maybe try the other answers.